# How to pass clicked item to a viewmodel that is observing another value?

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, observer-pattern

When I click on a view, it modifies X which is observed in the Fragment. I need to pass the clicked view to viewmodel.X.observe() method. I cannot set the viewmodel.X.observe inside the OnItemClickListener as it will try to create new observer each time an item is clicked. What would be the best way to pass the clicked item to the viewmodel.observe method? Is creating a global variable to hold the clicked item only option?

**Fragment code:**

```
lateinit var viewClicked: View
val itemClickListener =
        (object : OnItemClickListener<View> {
            override fun onItemClicked(item: View) {
                viewClicked = item
                //do something else
            }
        })

viewModel.signalStatus.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
        //Is viewClicked global my only option to be able to access here?
        // I can't have this observer inside my click listener as it will trigger this multiple times when user clicks on view
        if (viewClicked == btnView) {
            //do something
        } 
    })
```

Comment: ViewModel is not supposed to hold the View. It's better to learn more about [MVVM architecture](https://blog.mindorks.com/mvvm-architecture-android-tutorial-for-beginners-step-by-step-guide#:~:text=MVVM%20architecture%20is%20a%20Model,have%20the%20reference%20by%20observables.)  before using ViewModels. or watch some series on youtube.

Comment: @MRazaImtiaz this above code is in the fragment not viewmodel.

Comment: You cant do that, what do you want to achieve with passing the view? The usual way to go is to observe X and with a click listener change the value of X then the code inside `observe block` will be executed

Comment: you can try interface callback function maybe

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the global var.
Or group them into array, pass the index instead.